# Microsoft Access Database: How to Remove User & Password settings

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've got a MS Access database here that I can open in Access 2007 using a modified shortcut like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Temp\cat32.mdb" /wrkgrp "C:\Temp\cat32.mdw" /user "admin95" /pwd "somepassword"
```

I'm trying to import this database into our SQL Server environment, but pointing SQL Server at the Access database I want to import fails because I am logged in as another user. There is, in fact, no such user as `admin95`.

I could spend a few days writing a program that opens the database and copies everything over, but I'd rather just find a way to remove the owner tags or password requirements.

Notice, I don't think I can *just* remove the Password! I need to somehow add or change the Owner as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of luck:

- Check the permissions of every object that you need to access, including the database itself.
- Give full rights to user admin on all objects, or put Admin in the same groups as admin95
- Then finally remove password of user admin. You are done (maybe).  If it works, you can now open the db without reference to the

This is all done using the Tools, Security menu.

If that's unsuccessfull, try creating a blank db (without security) and export all objects from your locked mdb to that new mdb.

Hope it works, good luck. More reading [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/remove-user-level-security-mdb-HP005188240.aspx).

Comment: I think that worked! I'm now able to open the database without having to use the shortcut with the `wrkgrp`, `user`, and `pwd`. If I get the data imported to SQL Server here in a bit, I'll mark this as the answer.